# Unable to register adjuster in module

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2, modules

Following https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/v2/adjusters.html I am unable to register an adjuster in my module.

in my Module.php file I have placed the following inside init() alongside other stuff being registered (that are working)

```
use craft\events\RegisterComponentTypesEvent;
use craft\commerce\services\OrderAdjustments;
use modules\mymodule\adjusters\DiscountAdjuster;

Event::on(OrderAdjustments::class, 
    OrderAdjustments::EVENT_REGISTER_ORDER_ADJUSTERS, function(RegisterComponentTypesEvent $event) {
    $event->types[] = DiscountAdjuster::class;
});
```

And in src/adjusters/DiscountAdjuster.php I have

```
namespace modules\mymodule\adjusters;

use Craft;
use craft\base\Component;
use craft\commerce\base\AdjusterInterface;
use craft\commerce\elements\Order;
use craft\commerce\models\OrderAdjustment;

class DiscountAdjuster extends Component implements AdjusterInterface
{

    public function adjust(Order $order): array
    {
        $adjustments = [];

        foreach ($order->getLineItems() as $item) {
            $adjustment = new OrderAdjustment;
            $adjustment->type = 'discount';
            $adjustment->name = '$2 off';
            $adjustment->description = '$2 off everything in the store';
            $adjustment->sourceSnapshot = [ 'data' => 'value']; // This can contain information about how the adjustment came to be
            $adjustment->amount = -2;
            $adjustment->setOrder($order);
            $adjustment->setLineItem($item);

            $adjustments[] = $adjustment;
        }

        return $adjustments;
    }
}
```

This should take 2 off of every line item when I add items to the cart, no? Nothing happens though. And if i put something like `die()` in `public function adjust`, that isn't registered either.

What am I missing?

I also tried adapting this example: [Demo repo for an Adjuster module for Commerce 2?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/28184/demo-repo-for-an-adjuster-module-for-commerce-2) However I'm faced with the same issue.

Comment: Can you log something or `Craft::dd()` in your event listener?

Comment: I am almost curtain the module has not been bootstrapped. I had the same issue but have a Yii background and found the issue pretty quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, turns out I had Craft Commerce Lite installed when the feature requires the Pro version.

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure the module has bootstrapped? Check the app config and uncomment the bootstrap line